# vim quoting and escaping in command mode

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use ag (silver searcher) within Vim (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/faster-grepping-in-vim). I'm trying to be a bit more fancy and create a custom command to only search through files matching certain file extentions. I.e. use the `-G regex` pattern that `ag` supports.

This works except that trying to create a mapping for this has shown me that I don't have a good handle on quoting in this context.

The linked article shows a mapping such as this:
`nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>`

What I'd like is a second one which just checks the C files in a project.
Something like this except that this doesn't work because I can't figure out the required quoting:

`nnoremap ,k :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b" . '-G \.+(h<Bar>c)$'<CR>:cw<CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to this particularly confusing hell.

Let's start with the right command to use in the shell:

```
$ ag "\bfoo\b" -G '\.+(h|c)$'
```

Assuming we have the following line in our `vimrc`, as instructed in the linked post:

```
set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
```

If we try to use that `-G` flag as-is in `:help :grep`:

```
:grep! "\bfoo\b" -G '\.+(h|c)$'
```

we get this, from Vim:

```
:!ag --vimgrep "\bfoo\b" -G '\.+(h 2>&1| tee /var/folders/_d/bdwh8scx4hb1v2w__l0x6nk19ndqk1/T/vcaYrBc/6
```

this, from bash:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

and finally this, from Vim:

```
E426: tag not found: c)$
```

which tells us a) that the pattern is cut short before it reaches `ag` and b) that some part of the command even reaches Vim after the external command is executed, which is not desirable at this point.

The problem is the `|` in `h|c`, which is interpreted by Vim as a command separator so we send one part of the command to the shell and another part to Vim and everything is broken because both programs choke on what we send to them.

This is easy enough to fix, by escaping the bar:

```
:grep! "\bfoo\b" -G '\.+(h\|c)$'
```

And it works!

But not in a mapping:

```
nnoremap ,k :grep! "\b<C-r><C-w>\b" -G '\.+(h\|c)$'<CR>:cw<CR>
```

where we need yet another backslash:

```
nnoremap ,k :grep! "\b<C-r><C-w>\b" -G '\.+(h\\|c)$'<CR>:cw<CR>
```

because `\|` is expanded to `|` in this context so a second backslash is required to make sure we get an actual `\|`. See `:help map-bar`.

And we are done.

---

Note that you can do `--cc` as an alternative to `-G '\.+(h|c)$'`.

Comment: Just to note, `ag "\bfoo\b" -G \.+(h|c)$` is a syntax error in the shell. You need to quote the argument to `-G`: `ag "\bfoo\b" -G '\.+(h|c)$'`. The parentheses and the `|` are both special characters in the shell, and the `+(...)` could be as well, e.g. in `bash` with the `extglob` option set.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: If you have `extglob` set in `bash`, then it's not a syntax error, but there's the risk that the pattern actually *does* match something, and then `ag` never gets the regular expression as an argument.

Comment: @chepner, what do you suggest? 1. Adding the single quotes in every example, 2. Adding the single quotes only on the first one?

Comment: You can use single quotes for either, but the second argument should absolutely be quoted, because your *intent* is for it to be passed as a literal string to the program. Don't rely on it being an unmatched pattern which `bash` will treat as a literal string. (In `zsh`, the default is to treat an unmatched pattern as an error, not a literal string, so it's even more important to be explicit about your intent.)

Comment: @chepner, I think it looks better, now.

Comment: fantastic, thanks very much for the help with this, and more importantly, the explanation so I can do this myself next time. I spent more time fiddling with this than I care to admit. And that's a handy tip about the `--cc`